# particular groupby to daframe for analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I have this  data-frame with repetitive attributes:

```
 agentID, Name, Age, Profession   skills,     ratings
   002,    Rob,  32,  plumber,     bricklayer,  3
   002,    Rob,  32,  plumber,     plumber,     5
   002,    Rob,  32,  plumber,     carpenter,   3
   032,    john, 26, electrician,  welder,      5
   032,    john, 26, electrician,  electrician, 5
```

what I want is to groupby each agent by their agentID , profession age having grouping the repetitive together, so I can easily merge it with another csv file I have,  containing each employee college qualification. that other file only contains the agentID and college qualification to perform some analysis. what I want is to have the below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more rows to be aggregated? And if yes, how do you want them aggregated? (mean, sum etc). Currently you can get to your required output by simply using set_index()

```
df =  df.set_index(['agentID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Profession'])
```

You get

```
                                    skills  ratings
agentID Name    Age     Profession      
2       Rob     32      plumber     bricklayer  3
                        plumber     plumber     5
                        plumber     carpenter   3
32      john    26      electrician welder      5
                        electrician electrician 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `join`?

```
df.assign(New=df[[' agentID',' Name',' Age','Profession']].\
    apply(lambda x : ','.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)).\
      drop([' agentID',' Name',' Age','Profession'],axis=1)
Out[1207]: 
            skills       ratings                 New
0       bricklayer             3       002,Rob,32,  plumber
1          plumber             5       002,Rob,32,  plumber
2        carpenter             3       002,Rob,32,  plumber
3           welder             5       032,john,26, electrician
4      electrician             5       032,john,26, electrician
```